# ASP.NET Core migrations and NuGet packages

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

How do I fix this error?

> dotnet: Could not find any project in C:\Users\Pardy\source\repos\XXXXXXX\

Adding migrations on my file - I want to add this migration on my ASP.NET Core but for some reason I can't install the migration because it can't find the file. Yet the file is available in the path it cannot find. The aim is to write on SQL Server and create relational entities using my classes.

Comment: What command gave you that error? Give us more details like: os, net version, dotnet --info, a screen of your workspace tree, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try add like following:
`dotnet add <projectName> package <packageName>`
If you are lack of project name you may get the error.